# Correcting PHP version requirement in tagged release

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning

I'm using Composer and have recently made a mistake I do not know how to fix.

Version 2.1.0 of my package dropped support for PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4. However I forgot to change the version requirement in `composer.json`, which stayed at `>=5.3`. This release got tagged a few weeks ago. Since then the oversight in `composer.json` has been fixed, as it now correctly states `>=5.5` in release 2.2.0 and later.

The issue here is that people that have PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4, and install version `~2.0`, will now get `2.1.0`, as it's the latest (supposedly) matching release, after which their installation is broken.

How can I address this issue in a [SemVer](http://semver.org/) compliant manner?

Comment: I guess servers running php 5.3 and 5.4 will be stuck with a non functional version of your package. Never heard of a way to unpublish a version on composer/packagist, so I guess your only option will be to rollback to the files where things worked for php 5.3, publish it as new version, say 2.3, have it crawled, and only then release the >=5.5 version of the files, as 2.4. Messy.. I hope someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the tag from both the github repository and packagist.

Removing does not equal modifying. You're not moving the tag which would result in inconsistent repeat-ability.

Removing the tag simply makes it unavailable for any new/future users. Whoever is running it now, either has a broken install, or can safely update to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

This part of [the FAQ](http://semver.org/#what-do-i-do-if-i-accidentally-release-a-backwards-incompatible-change-as-a-minor-version) seems most relevant here:

> #### What do I do if I accidentally release a backwards incompatible change as a minor version?
>
> As soon as you realize that you’ve broken the Semantic Versioning spec, fix the problem and release a new minor version that corrects the problem and restores backwards compatibility. Even under this circumstance, it is unacceptable to modify versioned releases. If it’s appropriate, document the offending version and inform your users of the problem so that they are aware of the offending version.

You've already released the updated version, which is good.

You should definitely *not* remove the already released version, but instead just do your best to publicize the incompatibility for version `2.1.0` and PHP < 5.5.

Comment: This does not work in practice. Most people using this library don't even know they are using it, much less look at the README before they invoke Composer.

Comment: Problem is that if you remove a tagged version you potentially break someone's build, somewhere - packagist will tell you if your package is depended on so perhaps if it's not at all then you could reversion safely